# Why concatenate cause shape error in Keras even the inputs are right?

Tags: keras, concatenation

I am new to Keras and I have a code for the model part:

```
    # make inputs
    self.input_samples = Input(shape=(self.input_shape, ))
    self.input_labels = Input(shape=(self.nClass, ))

    # Encoder for samples
    self.E = self.encoder()(self.input_samples)
    # Encoder for labels
    self.E_LBLs = self.encoder4lbls()(self.input_labels)


    # Decoder for reconstruction
    self.D = self.decoder()(self.E)


    # Task network
    task_net = self.taskOut()
    self.T = task_net(self.E)
    self.T_LBLS = task_net(self.E_LBLs)


    # define GAN for prior matching for samples and labels
    self.A = self.adversarial()  # This is the discriminator for latent code matching

    print(type(self.E))

    self.Adv = self.A(concatenate([self.E, self.E_LBLs], axis=0))  # logits for samples and labels
    self.A.compile('Adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])

    # define MMD loss
    # self.merge_embeds = concatenate([self.E, self.E_LBLs], axis=0, name='mmd')

    model = Model([self.input_samples, self.input_labels], [self.E, self.E_LBLs, self.Adv])
```

When I want to output the self.Adv using `model.predict([inouts1, inputs2])`, it seems the concat operation in `concatenate([self.E, self.E_LBLs], axis=0)` . always wrong.

The error message is:

```
 res_list = model.predict([trainSamples, trainLabels])
  File "/DB/rhome/xchen/anaconda2/envs/Conda_python3_5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1835, in predict
    verbose=verbose, steps=steps)
  File "/DB/rhome/xchen/anaconda2/envs/Conda_python3_5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1339, in _predict_loop
    outs[i][batch_start:batch_end] = batch_out
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (64,1) into shape (32,1)
```

I am sure that `self.E` and `self.E_LBLs` are right. And their shapes are `[N1x2000]` and `[N2x2000]` respectively.

Do you have any idea? I cannot solve it.

Thanks.

Comment: From your error trace it seems that `model.predict` is throwing error. Are you sure you have posted correct error trace and relevant part of code?

Comment: yes, I am sure. I printed self.E and self.E_LBLs before and they are correct. But when I want to make the concatenation operation, it has error.

Comment: I am not talking about concat layer, your error trace is giving you error at `model.predict`. make sure that you are passing `[trainSamples, trainLabels]` correctly.

Comment: I think you need to `Flatten` after `concatenate`.

Comment: @ Vivek Mehta Yes, I am sure the inputs for model.predict are correct. Because I have used them to output self.E and self.E_LBLs.

Comment: @YOLO The inputs are Nx2048 and Nx7,  and it does not work. It seems that's not the problem.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with concatenation, as @VivekMehta mentioned, it happens inside model.predict. The traceback you posted does not match with the code you included.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro  Sorry, I still do not understand. If model.predict() is wrong, why I can successfully output self.E and self.E_LBLs ???

Comment: @XuChen do not ask us why, you are providing contradictory information, we are just interpreting your traceback